# XE5 Mobile tImage on click event from wrong image

Tags: android, ios, delphi-xe5

I am creating timage objects at run time and have a tag that identifies the image at the on click time. When the app is run on Android and IOS the click event appears to be from the wrong image. When the same app is run on Win32 all is fine and it works as expected.

The actual application is showing card images, and when clicked the image next to it (but partially overlapping) is triggered, not the actual image clicked. The emulator for IOS is very accurate as to where the click is happening because it is a mouse pointer. In the Android device it is a finger, but clearly tapping in the right spot. As I said in Windows all works accurately.

I should clarify one point. By clicking next to the card I mean the blank space next to the card in some cases. It reliably needs to be clicked to the left of the image you want to select. It is as though the O/S thinks the image is to the left of where it is actually showing.

Any suggestions why this is happening?

Comment: Could you clarify what is being "clicked" on: a web page (with ids in the html)? a ??

Comment: Native app, IOS emulator or Android device.

Comment: Check how the images are set to 'fill' the timage control. E.g., is it set to fill, stretch, etc. The actual TImage controls may actually be bigger than what you view by looking at the picture.

Comment: You are correct. It appears that images loaded from a resource file are a 1/4 the size of the original bitmaps. The sides are half of the originals. In addition the use of wrapmode has no effect on the mobiles, but OK in Windows. Whether you fit, original or stretch the results are the same, apart from putting the image in the middle, top left etc, the image is still the same size.